# Wpf String.Format cause dependencyproperty.unsetvalue

Tags: wpf, binding

This is the problem:

[image]

This is my XAML:

```
  <TextBlock>
         <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="My binding is: ({0})">
                <Binding Path="FieldThatDoesntExistYet"></Binding>
             </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

My datacontext is being loaded on run time, so It's end with the problem above.
Is there a simple XAML way to just show a default value ? empty or 0 will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a fallback value to your binding should do the trick.  Whatever is between the '' will be what is displayed if the binding is invalid.

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="My binding is: ({0})">
         <Binding Path="FieldThatDoesntExistYet" FallbackValue='0'></Binding>
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Liz! I wrote FallbackValue but apparently in the MultiBinding tag instead of  in the Binding.